# How do I make my Form the "Shell"?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm not even sure how to properly ask this but I am building a .Net Compact Framework Forms app for a small device with CE6.  I need to have a way for my Form to be Full Screen with no access to Start, the Taskbar, etc.

What's that called and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "kiosk mode" : see - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2007/06/01/kiosk-mode-for-ce-6-0.aspx

Comment: Yes, that blog post seems to have what you need. The registry keys can set which processes load and are dependent on each other. We've set our application to load before the Shell and the Shell to be dependent on our application. This way we get "kiosk mode" and if I want to get into windows we have a special escape sequence. In response to the sequence, the program signals the O/S with it's identifier and shuts down allowing the shell (explorer) to load.

Comment: @Alan Nice, that sounds VERY similar to what I need to do as well.  It's a TimeClock device with a touhcscreen that "Admins" would need to be able to drop it out of "kiosk mode".

Comment: @RefractedPaladin The identifier gets passed to the application command arguments. Then use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488242.aspx to signal its dependencies to load

Comment: @Alan Sure, I'll look into it.  Definitely is the way we want to go.  Don't be surprised to see a "Follow up" question on SO when I get that far... :)  Quick note, that link says Compact 2013, any idea if that applies to 3.5?  I'm stuck there unfortunately...

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Sure does, that's a Windows API function. CompactFramework versions doesn't matter. I use the same function in Windows CE 5.0 on CF 3.5. You'll have to p/invoke it `[DllImport("coredll.dll")]` `public extern static void SignalStarted(uint dw);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create full screen windows in .Net CF by simply setting "WindowState" property to 'Maximized' for the form.

As for completely blocking access to the Start menu, are you including the hardware buttons as well?  If so, you'll need to look into pinvoking some lower level functions to get handles for the Key Pressed event messages, and then just "Handle" those messages so they don't get passed onto the windowing system.  This could cause the device to stop functioning properly, however.

If you need help with that, let me know and I'll dig more into it.

Comment: This is not the correct approach for embedded systems.  CE supports true kiosk operation where the user application runs alone without the standard shell.  This is very important for some industrial machines, ATMs, airport ticket kiosks, etc.  For these applications, hacking as above is not the way to do it.

Comment: Ah, he wanted a Kiosk.  I saw Full Screen and thought he just wanted to have the app cover the whole screen.